# What is the difference between Microsoft.Extensions.Caching and System.Runtime.Caching?

Tags: .net, wpf

There are two packages for In-Memory Caching:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Caching
- System.Runtime.Caching

Which one is the most efficient for the WPF .NET Framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what framework you are using WPF on.

If using .NET Framework 4.6.0 or below, you won't be able to use the features of .NET Standard 2.0 as [it targets .NET Standard 1.3.](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard#versions)

In that case, use `System.Runtime.Caching`.

If not, then you will be targeting .NET Standard 2.0 with any version of .NET Framework starting 4.6.1 & any version of .NET Core from 2.0 and onwards.

In these scenarios, use `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` as it's [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0#systemruntimecachingmemorycache) over `System.Runtime.Caching` in all other circumstances:

> Use System.Runtime.Caching/MemoryCache as a compatibility bridge when porting code from ASP.NET 4.x to ASP.NET Core.